# SQL command to filter based on multiple tables and criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I am trying to learn sql, its driving me nuts. I cannot seem to grasp the proper syntax to achieve my desired output. I am watching videos on udemy and reading books on basic sql trying to teach myself, but it seems they all fall short in helping me bridge this gap I seem to not be able to over come.

I have a pretty good handle on the basics of the SELECT, FROM, WHEN commands. I seem to be gaining knowledge on using aggregate functions, but I am by no means an expert.

I have two tables, "Orders" and "OrderDet". "Orders" contains the CustomerName and the OrderNo, and OrderDet contains everything else, like PartNo, DateFinished, OrderNo, etc.

I have a situation where I can have multiple customers order the same part number. I want to show all the last orders all customers placed.

For example

```
SELECT Orders.CustDesc, OrderDet.OrderNo, OrderDet.PartNo, OrderDet.DateFinished
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderDet ON Orders.OrderNo = OrderDet.OrderNo
ORDER BY OrderDet.PartNo, OrderDet.DateFinished
```

This query returns:

```
Customer   OrderNo   PartNo     Date Finished
--------------------------------------------------------
Cust 1      5032    12345678-1  NULL
Cust 2     10032    12345678-1  2019-06-05 14:54:25.853
Cust 2      1048    12345678-1  2019-07-08 00:00:00.000
Cust 1      5028    12345678-1  2019-09-30 11:45:45.960
Cust 1      5029    12345678-1  2019-09-30 12:49:35.713
Cust 1      5030    12345678-1  2019-09-30 13:04:57.333
Cust 1      5031    12345678-1  2019-10-10 13:58:22.653
```

I'm still learning when and how to use aggregate function but seem to not be able to fully grasp the concept. I tried to use a MAX on the Date column and GROUP BY the Customer and PartNo, but unless I remove the Order Number, the output never collapses down to what I want.

For example I used:

```
SELECT Orders.CustDesc, OrderDet.PartNo, MAX(OrderDet.DateFinished)
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderDet ON Orders.OrderNo = OrderDet.OrderNo
GROUP BY Orders.CustDesc, OrderDet.PartNo
ORDER BY OrderDet.PartNo
```

Removing OrderDet.OrderNo from SELECT, and OrderDet.DateFinished from the Order By.
This returns the row output I desire, but lacking all the columns I want.

```
Customer  PartNo     Date Finished
--------------------------------------------
Cust 2  12345678-1  2019-07-08 00:00:00.000
Cust 1  12345678-1  2019-10-10 13:58:22.653
```

As soon as I try and add the OrderNo back into the mix, I get the same output as the first. I think I understand why this is happening because all the OrderNo's are unique and cannot get grouped, but I cant grasp how to over come this.

I understand this is a basic SQL command but I cannot seem to understand how to get the output I desire. In this example I wanted to only see the two rows of unique Customers based on the last date the PartNo was finished, but have the entire rows contents shown. Not just three columns.

Again, I am trying to learn this stuff and I can only read and re-read the same basic content to learn how to do this for so long. Everything I read seems to lack the info my brain seems to require for that "AH HA" moment.

Perhaps someone could help bridge this gap?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question as wanting the most recent order for a given customer for each part that customer has ordered.

For this, I would recommend window functions:

```
select CustDesc, OrderNo, od.DateFinished
from (select o.custdesc, od.orderno, od.partno, od.datefinished,
             row_number() over (partition by o.custdesc, od.partno order by od.datefinished desc) as seqnum
      from Orders o join
           orderdet od
           on o.OrderNo = od.OrderNo
     ) od
where seqnum = 1;
order by od.PartNo, od.DateFinished
```

Comment: This answer gave the results I wanted. Its a bit over my head though I need to try and understand what is going on. Your using commands I have not learned yet.

Comment: Is there a way to take this answer and form it into using basic commands for a beginner like me? Probably less efficient and longer, but it would help me understand how to think like sql maybe?